# JQuery same click function for multiple similar id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function like that to apply same event for multiple id with same attribute name.

```
<button id="hello">hello</button>
<button id="hello">hello</button>
```

and this is the JQuery function

```
$("#hello").click(function(event){
          window.alert("hello");
      });
```

but affects the first id. Someone know how I can perform the same effect for both ids.

Thanks

Comment: using multiple ids already causes problems and should be avoided

Comment: IDs must be unique. Use a class.

Comment: oh that's right. Sorry for be new in this topics... thanks everyone.